# C++ finding the function return type

Tags: c++, arrays

I am very new to C++ and not too sure what I need to provide to provide a minimum reproducible example, but here is my question anyway:

In C++, I would like to create a function (f1) that has the ability to have another function (f2), as an input, which would get evaluated in a loop and recorded/outputed.

But depending on the output type of the function (f2) the output of f1 has to change. I.e. If f2 outputs a double then I will need an array/vector as the output type of f1 but if f2 outputs an array/vector then I will need a 2-dimensional array/matrix as the output type of f1. Is there anything that will be able to help me find out before carrying out the loop the return type of f1?

Any help or examples that I could follow would be much appreciated.

Comment: A simple template should be able to do this.

Comment: Function templates are the answer. You'll need specialization if you want to be able to return an array from f2 tho.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're looking for templates. You could start here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_%28C%2B%2B%29 here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y097fkab.aspx or here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/257589/An-Idiots-Guide-to-Cplusplus-Templates-Part-1

Templates allow you to write a function or class once, and have it work on different data types. Keep in mind that if the code has to change between data types you will need more complicated templates - specialization - or it could be that templates are not what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a work for templates

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_templates.htm

Be sure to make your functions work in general, for many types I mean both f1 and f2. You may need to create operators for your custom class if you want to use calculations and comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

A template is the right way to go. Here's a function that takes any callable object, `f`, and returns a `std::array` of the return type (5 elements chosen at random) filled with returned values from calling the function ([live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4cccc23b51a40253)):

```
template<typename F>
auto foo(F f) -> std::array<decltype(f()), 5> { //decltype(f()) is return type
    std::array<decltype(f()), 5> ret;
    std::fill(std::begin(ret), std::end(ret), f()); //fill ret with values
    return ret;
}
```

Note that the only thing that changes if the functions passed in have any parameters is that `f()`, in all cases, would need to become `f(arg1, arg2, ...)`. Also note that this fills the array with copies of the result of calling `f` once. If you'd like to call `f` once per element, use `std::generate` and replace `f()` with `f`. If you do use `std::generate`, though, and the function has parameters, you'd have to use something like `std::bind`, and that's really getting off topic.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to find the result type of an ordinary function is IMHO to use `std::function`.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template< class Function >
using Pure_function_ = typename remove_pointer<Function>::type;

template< class Function >
using Result_type_ = typename function<Pure_function_<Function>>::result_type;

template< class Function >
auto three_times( Function f )
    -> vector< Result_type_<Function> >
{
        vector< Result_type_<Function> > result;
        for( int x : {1, 2, 3} )
        {
            result.push_back( f( x ) );
        }
        return result;
}

auto double_foo( int x ) -> double { return 2*x; }
auto vector_foo( int x ) -> vector<int> { return vector<int>( 5, 3*x ); }

auto main()
    -> int
{
    auto const  a   = three_times( double_foo );
    cout << typeid( function<decltype(double_foo)>::result_type ).name() << endl;

    auto const  b   = three_times( vector_foo );
    cout << typeid( b ).name() << endl;

    auto const  c   = three_times( &vector_foo );
    cout << typeid( c ).name() << endl;    // Same as above.
}
```